# Contiguous Hex file generation using GCC

Tags: c, gcc, stm32, bootloader, hex-file

I have a Hex file for STM32F427 that was built using GCC(gcc-arm-none-eabi) version 4.6 that had contiguous memory addresses. I wrote boot loader for loading that hex file and also added checksum capability to make sure Hex file is correct before starting the application. 
Snippet of Hex file:

:10**05C8**0018460AF02FFE07F5A64202F1D00207F5F9
:10**05D8**008E4303F1A803104640F6C821C2F2000179
:10**05E8**001A460BF053F907F5A64303F1D003184652
:10**05F8**000BF068F907F5A64303F1E80340F6FC1091
:10**0608**00C2F2000019463BF087FF07F5A64303F145
:10**0618**00E80318464FF47A710EF092FC07F5A643EA
:10**0628**0003F1E80318460EF03DFC034607F5A64221
:10**0638**0002F1E0021046194601F0F2FC07F56A5390

As you can see all the addresses are sequential. Then we changed the compiler to version 4.8 and i got the same type of Hex file.

But now we used compiler version 6.2 and the Hex file generated is not contiguous. It is somewhat like this:

```
:10016000B9BC0C08B9BC0C08B9BC0C08B9BC0C086B
:10017000B9BC0C08B9BC0C08B9BC0C08B9BC0C085B
:08018000B9BC0C08B9BC0C0865
:1001900081F0004102E000BF83F0004330B54FEA38
:1001A00041044FEA430594EA050F08BF90EA020FA5
```

As you can see after 0188 it is starting at 0190 means rest of 8 bytes(0189 to 018F) are 0xFF as they are not flashed.

Now boot loader is kind of dumb where we just pass the starting address and no of bytes to calculate the checksum.

Is there a way to make hex file in contiguous way as compiler 4.6 and compiler 4.8? the code is same in all the three times.

Comment: Perhaps instead fix the boot-loader/function call to accept `:08018000B9BC0C08B9BC0C0865` (8 bytes at address 0180).   I  think the goal of "make hex file in contiguous" is not the best approach.

Comment: The line length isn't specified, it can be anything.

Comment: Well then whenever I change the hex file ..I might need to change the bootloader. Version 4.6 and 4.8 behaves correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If post-processing the hex file is an option, you can consider using the [IntelHex](https://pypi.org/project/IntelHex/) python library. This lets you manipulate hex file data (i.e. ignoring the 'markup'; record type, address, checksum etc) rather than as lines, will for instance create output with the correct line checksum.

A fast way to get this up and running could be to use the bundled convenience scripts [hex2bin.py](http://python-intelhex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/part3-1.html) and [bin2hex.py](http://python-intelhex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/part3-2.html):

```
python hex2bin.py --pad=FF noncontiguous.hex tmp.bin
python bin2hex.py tmp.bin contiguous.hex
```

The first line converts the input file `noncontiguous.hex` to a binary file, padding it with `FF` where there is no data. The second line  converts it the binary file back to a hex file.

The result would be

```
:08018000B9BC0C08B9BC0C0865
```

becomes

```
:10018000B9BC0C08B9BC0C08FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF65
```

As you can see, padding bytes are added where the input doesn't have any data, equivalent to writing the input file to the device and reading it back out. Bytes that are in the input file are kept the same - and at the same address.
The checksum is also correct as changing the length byte from `0x08` to `0x10` compensates for the extra `0xFF` bytes. If you padded with something else, IntelHex would output the correct checksum

You can skip the the creation of a temporary file by piping these: omit `tmp.bin` in the first line and replacing it with `-` in the second line:

```
python hex2bin.py --pad=FF noncontiguous.hex | python bin2hex.py - contiguous.hex
```

An alternative way could be to have a base file with all `FF` and use the `hexmerge.py` convenience script to merge gcc's output onto it with `--overlap=replace`

The longer, more flexible way, would be to implement your own tool using the IntelHex API. I've used this to good effect in situations similar to yours - tweak hex files to satisfy tools that are costly to change, but only handle hex files the way they were when the tool was written.

Comment: I think that might not be the best idea as Hex file might have jump institution to specific address. If we move the bytes without considering the address change then application would fail. I don't want to do any post processing. I want GCC to behave consistently

Comment: Existing bytes aren't moved. The bytes in the that are defined are untouched - same value, same address. Padding is inserted where no data is defined

Comment: Some HEX files intend the data to start at a certain 32-bit address. For instance 0x60000000. This is stored as a special record type (4) in the HEX file. However, after the hex2bin/bin2hex treatment this information is lost. Now your data may suddenly start at address 0. Fortunately the bin2hex tool supports the --offset command line option so you can influence this. However you must still be careful because your HEX file might contain more than one section that is required to be at a certain offset in memory. If you are working with microcontrollers such a broken file can brick the device.

Answer (score 1):

One of many possible ways:

- Make your hex file with v6.2, e.g., `foo.hex`.
- Postprocess it with this Perl oneliner:

  ```
  perl -pe 'if(m/^:(..)(.*)$/) { my $rest=16-hex($1); $_ = ":10" . $2 . ("FF" x $rest) . "\n"; }' foo.hex > foo2.hex
  ```

Now `foo2.hex` will have all 16-byte lines

Note: *all this does* is FF-pad to 0x10 bytes.  It doesn't check addresses or anything else.

**Explanation**

`perl -pe '<some script>' <input file>` runs `<some script>` for each line of `<input file>`, and prints the result.  The script is:

```perl
if(m/^:(..)(.*)$/) {         # grab the existing byte count into $1
    my $rest=16 - hex($1);   # how many bytes of 0xFF we need
    $_ = ":10" . $2 . ("FF" x $rest) . "\n";  # make the new 16-byte line
# existing bytes-^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-pad bytes
}
```

Comment: I think that might not be the best idea as Hex file might have jump institution to specific address. If we move the bytes without considering the address change then application would fail. I don't want to do any post processing. I want GCC to behave consistently

Comment: @DheerajKumar Fair enough.  Then, for clarification: In the testcase in your question, the `ff` bytes are omitted, but the addressing is still consistent.  There are eight bytes at 0x0180, eight omitted bytes, then bytes starting at 0x190 (16 bytes after 0x180).  Are there other situations in which, say, one record is at 0x180 and the next is at 0x1a0 (or something else other than 16 bytes later)?  If not, the postprocessing should work.

Comment: Other case is not there .. this is the only case. I will try and see if app still works. Thanks for your support though :)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to change the linker script to ensure the preceding .isr_vector section ends on a 16 byte alignment, as the mapfile reveals that the following .text section is 16 byte aligned.
This will ensure there is no unprogrammed flash bytes between the two sections

Answer (score 1):

You can use [bincopy](https://github.com/eerimoq/bincopy) to fill all empty space with 0xff.

```
$ pip install bincopy
$ bincopy fill foo.hex
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`-gap-fill`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objcopy.html#:%7E:text=Fill%20gaps%20between%20sections%20with%20val.%20This%20operation%20applies%20to%20the%20load%20address%20(LMA)%20of%20the%20sections.%20It%20is%20done%20by%20increasing%20the%20size%20of%20the%20section%20with%20the%20lower%20address%2C%20and%20filling%20in%20the%20extra%20space%20created%20with%20val.) option of `objcopy`, e.g.:

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy --gap-fill 0xFF -O ihex firmware.elf firmware.hex
```